# clause.OnConflict() doesn't generate where condition during UPSERT

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm using golang with gorm and running on Postgres and need to do an Upsert. Any help is appreciated.

I'm inserting into an "attributes" table and on conflict of "id" the row should be updated only when the "organization_id" matches the given value.

Based on samples from
https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Upsert-On-Conflict and https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/master/clause/where_test.go

```
result := tx.Table("attributes").Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
    Columns: []clause.Column{{Table: "attributes", Name: "id"}},
    Where:     clause.Where{Exprs: []clause.Expression{clause.Eq{Column: "organization_id", Value: "2"}}},
    UpdateAll: true,
}).Create(&attributes)
```

Above code generates the following SQL **without WHERE clause**:

```
INSERT INTO "attributes" ("organization_id","name","id") 
VALUES (2,"demo",15)
ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "organization_id"="excluded"."organization_id", "name"="excluded"."name",
RETURNING "id"
```

Expected SQL with WHERE clause:

```
INSERT INTO "attributes" ("organization_id","name","id") 
VALUES (2,"demo",15)
ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "organization_id"="excluded"."organization_id", "name"="excluded"."name",
WHERE attributes.organization_id=2 
RETURNING "id"
```

Comment: Fixed it. **First**, upgrade to latest version of gorm. **Second**, Remove this line `Columns: []clause.Column{{Table: "attributes", Name: "id"}},`